# When does my machine know its DNS?

Tags: dns, arp

Assuming I have not setup a proxy server, how does my windows-based machine know my dns? Is this also determined with filling the arp table gateway entry? Or is DNS "solved" after ARP by another process?  Thanks...

When does my machine know its own DNS entry?

Comment: Are you asking about the DNS servers your computer is configured to use? Are you asking about any DNS name that points to your computer? Something else?

Comment: dns and arp have absolutely nothing to do with each other. arps map IPs to MACS. an IP can be tied to a name via DNS, but a machine need never arp itself as it already knows its MAC and IP

Comment: So, to respond to Frank's comment: while arp and dns have nothing to do with each other, your computer cannot look at its gateway settings without first having done an arp.  Correct?  Nerdwaller: What if I was in a large public library? Would that machine have to be specifically configured to a DNS server in the library.

Comment: DNS is a static mapping of names to IPs, so the name exists before the computer boots and continues to exist after it has shut down. both names and IPs are external phenomena. your system knows its DNS name as soon as it bothers to ask the DNS server what it is.

Comment: @NAs, it depends. if you use DHCP, your connection to the DNS server is done via broadcast frames, so no ARP required. the DHCP server will specify your IP, GateWay, and DNS server addresses.

Comment: Routers broadcast themselves, which is how your computer knows that even exists.  Once it connects, if it doesn't know the DNS settings, it gets them from the gateway (i.e. the router usually).  In a library type of environment, there would usually be a domain controller that provides this information down the line.  Perhaps I am missing the meat of your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will know if it gets the DHCP answer from your router. But it will really use it only if it had your ip-level network configured. Between them is normally 1-3 seconds. ARP has only with this to do, because the DHCP gives only the IP-Address of the DNS, to send him packets (thus ask the ip-addresses of hostnames from that), first an arp resolution is needed. So the relevant packets are the following:

1: windows asks his dhcp settings with an udp broadcast
2: your dhcp server (normally your router) gives him this back
3: windows configures his ip settings with the got values
4: windows asks the mac address of your dns (and before your first outgoing packet, your routers) with an arp request (which is just broadcasted udp)
5: the asked servers says their mac addresses (with normal udp)